# sql server check for greater than with select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Why can't I do something like this:

```
    select distinct ps.ID, from vwList wt
    where Flag = 1 
    and GETDATE()  < (select dbo.fn_Date(ps.date1,ps.UploadDate) from pseres ps where ps.ID = wt.ID)
```

I get The multi-part identifier "ps.ID" could not be bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the outer select.  Try this:

```
select distinct wt.ID
from vwList wt
where Flag = 1 and
      GETDATE()  < (select dbo.fn_Date(ps.date1,ps.UploadDate) from pseres ps where ps.ID = wt.ID)
```

Comment: @Gordan Linoff - is it correct I need to do the following: PS is in an inner select in the where clause. If you want to select the column from pseres then you need to have it in the from clause or as a join as Greg mentioned.

Comment: @NatePet . . . That is correct.  However, you can't have a correlated subquery in the from clause for a join.  But, you can have a correlated subquery with an APPLY, instead of a JOIN.

Comment: Lindoff - So does this mean what I have is correct and will work?

Comment: I don't know what you have. Just referencing the table in the outer "from" will work (wt.id rather than ps.id). Your query should work, assuming that the subquery always returns exactly one row. I would be inclined to put in a max() or min() around dbo.fn_Date(ps.date1,ps.UploadDate), just in case.

Answer (score 2):

Since ps.ID matches wt.ID, and ps is only mentioned in a subquery, why not:

```
select distinct wt.ID from vwList wt
```

?

Answer (score 0):

PS is in an inner select in the where clause. If you want to select the column from pseres then you need to have it in the from clause or as a join.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT wt.ID
FROM vwList wt
    INNER JOIN (SELECT dbo.fn_Date(ps.date1,ps.UploadDate) AS MyDate FROM pseres) ps ON     wt.ID = ps.ID
WHERE Flag = 1 AND
      MyDate > GETDATE()
```